# Where to code when leave a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, destroy

I am using `spring mvc` and storing some data in session. I want to delete those data when the user leave that menu and moved to next menu. I don't know where to code for it.

Also if the user is clicking other menu and if that page have any unsaved data, I want to get confirmation from the user.

Is `jspDestroy()` will help me for this.

Please help me.

Comment: session.invalidate() will delete all the session

Comment: No i dont want to delete all the data in session just one or two attribute which i used particularly in that page

Comment: it will be easy to understand the scenario if you show you jsp code

Comment: @MonickaAkilan then use setAttribute()

Comment: @jqueryLearner Thanks for ur suggestion. But My problem is i dont know where to put that code. Which method will call when the user move to another page.

Comment: Why are you storing data in session which is page specific? Just maintain data using request,response.

Comment: No am using display tag am storing the list in session it will populate every time when the user use pagination and all if am not putting that value in session means then every time the data is retrieving from database. But when the user move to next page i want to clear that list.

Comment: next menu menu means is it show a  new page or same page itself

Comment: No new page if the user works in same page i want to maintain the session object only when he move to next page i want clear those session data

Comment: You can put in `request` scope using `request.setAttribute("list",list);` Why session???  Next page means what? another menu or paging within display tag?

Comment: For every request am redirecting to a common url after completion of all process so request object wont help me thats why i put in session

Comment: ok then why you are setting the session if you dont need all those things in the next page.Only set the attributes that you need in the next page in session.otherwise in the new page you can use session.removeattribute

Comment: Ya like that only am doing now. But i dont know which page user will click next so i want to remove that session object in all pages

Comment: Down voter please explain the reason so that i could ask better

Comment: continue in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45875/question-for-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the various comments above your problem is little bit clear, you want to perform some action when user is leaving the current page.

You can use [`unload` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-unload)

```
window.onunload = function(){
 //give ajax call here and remove whatever you want to remove from session
}
```

---

`unload` event

> A user agent must dispatch this event when the DOM Implementation removes from the environment the resource (such as the document) or any dependent resources (such as images, style sheets, scripts). The document must be unloaded after the dispatch of this event type.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you want to remove some particular objects not all so you can use [session.removeAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#removeAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)

For removing all sessions use [session.invalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29)

Comment: @MonickaAkilan It depends on how you use it.I dont know how you are calling menu or any ids given to it or not.I will suggest create a id for menu and via ajax call a jsp/servlet that will remove attributes

Comment: I elaborate my issue how to identify in web application when the user leave a page and moved to next page. If that found means what java method will call when a new jsp loaded

Comment: @MonickaAkilan this is simple,if you are going to some other page then its understood that you are leaving the current page,As I said before use an id and use click event using javascript or jquery